# Creating a series of dropdown menus based on an Object with key: [array of dropdown options] pairs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I've been having a LOT of trouble with this problem for the past couple days. Basically, I'm trying to create a series of dropdown menus based on a JSON return from a database. I was able to have it working just fine and dandy 2 days ago, but we just rewrote our backend code to return a differently formatted JSON and I have to rewrite a lot of stuff to get it working. The format of our name JSON is this:

```
provisions: {
   NAME OF DROPDOWN MENU1: [VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3, ..],
   NAME OF DROPDOWN MENU2: [VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3, ..],
   NAME OF DROPDOWN MENU3: [VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3, ..]
}
```

Based on that JSON, I want to create 3 dropdown menus that has the associated values within them. I also want to be able to display whatever the previously saved data return the server is (for example, if the user Selects Value 2 in the first dropdown and saves the page, the first dropdown will display Value 2 the next time they access that page).

Here is the HTML that I currently have to try and display the dropdown menus:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="GamePreferenceCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(name, section) in gameConfigs">
        <label ng-bind="name"></label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="formData.settings[$index].value" ng-change="dropdownItemClicked(name, formData.settings[$index].value)">
            <option value="" disabled="disabled">---Please Select Option---</option>
            <option ng-repeat="item in section" value="{{item.value}}" ng-bind="item.value"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" ng-include="gametemp"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
        <div class="text-center col-md-12 padding-15">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="saveGameSetting()" formnovalidate translate>
                <i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin' ng-if="showBusy"></i>&nbsp;Save
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The way that's written will display the dropdown menus with the appropriate name above them, but every option in the dropdown is blank. Any help on this is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `provisions` means `gameConfigs` or what? Also, would be great if you could post a useful `object`/`array`..

Comment: yes, gameConfigs is an object that I create in my controller. My controller is set up to check to see if there is a provisions object that's return from the API, and if there is, to create a gameConfigs object that is the exact same structure as the provisions object. I don't know how to be more clear about the structure of the object array, besides something like:
provisions: {
      food: ["burger", "burrito"],
      drink: ["coke", "sprite", "mountain dew"],
      dessert: ["sundae"]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing this instead?

`<option ng-repeat="item in section" value="{{item.value}}">{{item.value}}</option>`

I'm not sure that `ng-bind` has access to `item.value`, because `ng-repeat` is on the same element, so that may work better.

Comment: Oh man. I think I've been staring at this so much that my brain turned to mush. I just realized I needed to change the value to "{{item"}} instead of "{{item.value}}". The options appear in the dropdown menus correctly now. Thank you for pointing that out. 

Now, for the really hard part, which is making previously saved values appear by default in the dropdown menus. Which I will also glady take any help on.

Comment: @amacdonald maybe `label="item.value"` works also. But I recommend you to use [**`ngOptions`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead of `ngRepeat`.

Comment: How are the previously saved values saved? Shouldn't be hard to do by using `ng-selected="expression"`

Comment: I have an ng-change set up on the select class that watches for the name and the value the user clicked on, which is why the ng-model is set to `formData.settings[$index.value`. It then creates an object which gets sent to the API in the form of `{NAME OF DROPDOWN MENU: VALUE}` and responds with `{NUMERIC KEY: {NAME OF DROPDOWN MENU, VALUE}}` and so on. I don't have any experience with ng-selected.